# Query to count combinations of many In a many-to-one relationship?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have two tables: projects and measures. Multiple measures can be associated with one project, but only one project is associated with each measure. I need a query that counts and orders the unique combination of measures.

For example, a project may have measures X, Y, and Z. Another project may have measures A, B, C. Another project may have measures X, A, C.

I want to count the number of projects associated with every possible combination of measures. How many projects have X, Y, Z? How many have A, B, X? Ultimately I'm looking for the most common combinations.

Thanks.

Comment: It would be helpful with some example data and the expected result. Also, you list three measures only; but what is the maximum? And combinations can quickly rise to very high figures.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have created a proper relationship between the two tables. This should be a very simple query.
Essential what you want is a count of measure for project x
You can build a query like this:

```
SELECT Measures.Count(*)
FROM Project Join Measures
WHERE Project.Name = [Parameter Here]
```

If you build a query and create a parameter, all you have to do is put the Project Name into the parameter pop up when you run the query and it will give you the total number of measures per project.

If you want to know how many of each measure are per project use a `GROUP BY` statement and group By the Project then by Measure.

Then simply ORDER them as needed.

If you dont know how to use group by statements you should a lil bit of research before asking just for an answer.
Here is one resource: [w3schools sql statements resource](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp)

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you Erick. I promise I did some research! Stack may not be the best venue for this question. I haven't been able to use your help to get what I'm looking for but I really appreciate the direction.